# procedural eyeball turns from transparent to white when moving the origin to the world origin

Tags: mirror-modifier

My procedural eyeball turns from transparent to white when moving the origin to the world origin (center of it all), I have to put the world origin at the center of it all in order for the eye ball to work properly with a mirror MOD I'm putting on at usual. standard eyeball mirroring for a head sculpt, X+ to -x. To be more specific the eyeball goes white and I can no longer see the IRIs (bad), I know why its doing it that's the thing I just do not know how to solve this I've tried and need help at this point please. MY theory is: I have a shader on it, material shader's to be specific, it is on the sclera mesh: (Repair and current whites and iris Experiment), THe issue comes from the texture coordinates shader being connected at the OBJECT point according to me? I might be wrong, but yes please if anyone can help me find a balanced solution it would be awesome.  google drive below

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dcn9eHhIOAF83Jr1uOt4UPmipLWlFGtk?usp=drive_link

Comment: helloooooo help anyone?????????????????????????????????????